# Regex match only if instance occurs once

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a Regex validation for my rule in C#. I have the following rule:

> @N [currency] [sign] size [sign] [currency]

- currency: `([$]|[~][^~]*[~])?`
- sign: `-`
- size: `[1-9][0-9]*`  (only size is obligatory)

Here is the Regex: `[@][nN]([$]|[~][^~]*[~])?-?[1-9][0-9]*-?([$]|[~][^~]*[~])?`

My problem is that currency and sign should occur only once, either on left or right of size.That means if sign is already on left of size it should not occur on the right anymore, the same goes for currency.

Is this possible to do this with Regular Expressions ?

The following should match:

- @N$7-
- @N-7$
- @N$-7
- @N7-$

The following should **not** match:

- @N$5$
- @N$-5-
- @N-5-

Comment: What about `@N7$-` and `@N-$7`, should these be matched or rejected?

Comment: The simplest way is to create multiple regexes with the ^ and $ and put them in | (or).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight @N7$- should not match. Because the sign must be before currency (according to rule).  @N-$7 should also not match according to rule.

Comment: @xanatos could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Do you need only a Yes/No match, or are you planning to harvest the matched values from capturing groups? Would a solution that relies partially on regex and partially on C# code interpreting the match work for your purposes?

Comment: [Here another one with use of neg lookaheads](https://regex101.com/r/A1lqdj/1/).

Comment: Posting here the solution of @bobblebubble which works good so it does not get lost: `^@[nN](?:(?:\$|~[^~]*~)(?!.*?[$~]))?(?:-(?!.*?-))?[1-9]\d*-?(?:\$|~[^~]*~)?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may disallow a pattern to repeat by using construct `^(?!.*pattern.*pattern)`. For your case the regex would look as follows:

```
(?mx)^
(?!.*([$]|~[^~]*~).*([$]|~[^~]*~))
(?!.*-.*-)
@[nN]([$]|~[^~]*~)?-?[1-9][0-9]*-?([$]|~[^~]*[~])?$
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/YBhQPB/1

C# demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8jG3y4

Comment: I like this one as it is easy to expand the rule plus I did not know that something like this was possible. That is something new for me to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if C# supports conditionnal expression, but if it does, you could use:

```
\@[nN](\$)?(-)?[1-9]\d*(?(2)|-)(?(1)|\$)(?:\s|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\@[nN]      : @ followed by n case insensitive
(\$)?       : optional $ sign captured in group 1
(-)?        : optional minus sign captured in group 2
[1-9]\d*    : value
(?(2)|-)    : if group 2 exists then nothing, else minus sign
(?(1)|\$)   : if group 1 exists then nothing, else $ sign
(?:\s|$)    : a space or end of line
```

Here is a sample perl script:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr~\@[nN](\$)?(-)?[1-9]\d*(?(2)|-)(?(1)|\$)(?:\s|$)~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK: $_" : "KO: $_");
}
__DATA__
@N$7-
@N-7$
@N$-7
@N7-$
@N$5$
@N$-5-
@N-5-
@N7$-
@N-$7
```

**Output:**

```
OK: @N$7-
OK: @N-7$
OK: @N$-7
OK: @N7-$
KO: @N$5$
KO: @N$-5-
KO: @N-5-
KO: @N7$-
KO: @N-$7
```

Comment: .NET supports conditional expressions. Although it does not fulfill the original rule as @N7 should also be a match. Tested on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with a regex solution that runs additional tests in C#, you can write a simple method to verify that only one of two groups captures a value:

```
static bool HasOnlyOne(Match m, int g1, int g2) {
    if (!m.Success) {
        return false;
    }
    var has1 = m.Groups[g1].Success;
    var has2 = m.Groups[g2].Success;
    return !has1 || !has2;
}
```

With this function in hand, you can use a slightly modified version of your regex to perform tests as follows:

```
var r = new Regex(
    @"^[@][nN]([$]|[~][^~]*[~])?(-)?[1-9][0-9]*(-)?([$]|[~][^~]*[~])?$"
    //                          ^ ^            ^ ^
);
string s;
while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    var m = r.Match(s);
    bool good = HasOnlyOne(m, 1, 4) && HasOnlyOne(m, 2, 3);
    if (good) {
        Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}", s);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Fail: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YKNJaw)

I marked modifications to your regex with `^` marks in the comments.